# Infinite intersection of sets of multiples of naturals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is a example in my Set Theory Book that is giving me trouble:

$$\cap_{i=10}^{\infty}D_i=\emptyset, D_i=multiples\;of\;i\;in\;\mathbb{N}.$$
For me, every time I do and intersection, there will be aways a set of numbers that will be there, since I can just multiply tem for the intersected number (i).

I have shown something like these:
$$D_{10}\cap D_{11}\dots D_x=\cap_{i=10}^x=\{z:z=10.11.12(\dots).x.m\;|\;m\in\mathbb{N}\},$$
and then tryed to limit this to $\infty$. But I don't know how to finish it without bias.

Comment: Isn't it enough to note that that $i \notin D_{i+1}$. (And also that none of the numbers less than 10 are in $D_{11}$.)

Comment: BTW, I added my comment, which uses a completely different approach than yours, because I don't think your approach of characterizing the finite intersections can be completed to answer the infinite intersection question. Happy to be proved wrong, but that's my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Take an $x\in\bigcap_{i=10}^\infty D_i$, then for every $i\geq 10$ we have $x\in D_i$, so $i$ has to divide $x$. If we use $0\notin\mathbb{N}$ then we can conclude $i\leq x$ for every $i\geq 10$. Since $x\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\infty\notin\mathbb{N}$, there is no such $x$. Therefore $\bigcap_{i=10}^\infty D_i=\emptyset$.

There is a different proof using the limits you mentioned:
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{i\rightarrow\infty}D_i
=\bigcap_{i\geq 1}\bigcup_{j\geq i}D_j
=\bigcap_{i\geq 1}\{n\in\mathbb{N}|n\geq i\}=\emptyset
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bigcap_{j\geq 10}D_j
\subseteq\bigcup_{i\geq 1}\bigcap_{j\geq i}D_j
=\liminf_{i\rightarrow\infty}D_i
\subseteq\limsup_{i\rightarrow\infty}D_i=\emptyset.
\end{equation}